# DCM4CHE refuse some DICOM with org.dcm4che3.net.NoPresentationContextException

Tags: dicom, dcm4che

I have to run a DCM4CHE3 server, and some DICOM are refused with this message

> org.dcm4che3.net.NoPresentationContextException: No Presentation
>   Context for Abstract Syntax: 1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.6.1 - Ultrasound
>   Image Storage negotiated

From documentation

> 1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.6.1   Ultrasound Image Storage

If I check in service=StoreScp / AcceptedImageSOPClasses I have

```
ComputedRadiographyImageStorage
DigitalXRayImageStorageForPresentation
DigitalXRayImageStorageForProcessing
DigitalMammographyXRayImageStorageForPresentation
DigitalMammographyXRayImageStorageForProcessing
DigitalIntraoralXRayImageStorageForPresentation
DigitalIntraoralXRayImageStorageForProcessing
CTImageStorage
EnhancedCTImageStorage
UltrasoundMultiframeImageStorage
MRImageStorage
EnhancedMRImageStorage
EnhancedMRColorImageStorage
UltrasoundImageStorage
EnhancedUSVolumeStorage
SecondaryCaptureImageStorage
MultiframeSingleBitSecondaryCaptureImageStorage
MultiframeGrayscaleByteSecondaryCaptureImageStorage
MultiframeGrayscaleWordSecondaryCaptureImageStorage
MultiframeTrueColorSecondaryCaptureImageStorage
XRayAngiographicImageStorage
EnhancedXRayAngiographicImageStorage
XRayRadiofluoroscopicImageStorage
EnhancedXRayRadiofluoroscopicImageStorage
XRay3DAngiographicImageStorage
XRay3DCraniofacialImageStorage
BreastTomosynthesisImageStorage
NuclearMedicineImageStorage
VLEndoscopicImageStorage
VLMicroscopicImageStorage
VLSlideCoordinatesMicroscopicImageStorage
VLPhotographicImageStorage
OphthalmicPhotography8BitImageStorage
OphthalmicPhotography16BitImageStorage
OphthalmicTomographyImageStorage
PositronEmissionTomographyImageStorage
EnhancedPETImageStorage
RTImageStorage
HardcopyGrayscaleImageStorage
HardcopyColorImageStorage
NuclearMedicineImageStorageRetired
UltrasoundMultiframeImageStorageRetired
UltrasoundImageStorageRetired
XRayAngiographicBiPlaneImageStorageRetired
VLImageStorageRetired
VLMultiframeImageStorageRetired
```

I don't find any help for this error so far.

Comment: It was a problem with the client side, not a DCM4CHEE configuration issue. And client side code is not available to me.

Answer (score 1):

try adding  UltrasoundImageStorage in AcceptedImageSOPClasses (Ypou can add sop-classes.properties for your accepted formats.)

Answer (score 0):

A presentation context exception could also have to do with the transfer syntax. It looks like the SOP class is acceptable. I'd recommend verifying the TS is valid and supported.

Comment: TS as TransferSyntax ? (ExplicitVRLittleEndian for example). I am a noob in DCM4CHE.

Comment: Yes, Transfer Syntax.

Comment: Yes, it is.    
 
It was a problem with the client side, not a DCM4CHEE configuration issue. And client side code is not available to me.

Thanks.